# Error while inserting data in table with Composite primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have table

```
create table INVOICE
(
  brok_dlr_code     VARCHAR2(20),
  invoice_date      DATE,
  ba_trxn_date_from DATE,
  ba_trxn_date_to   DATE,
  mf_invoice_no     VARCHAR2(40)
);
```

I created composite primary key

```
ALTER TABLE BROKER_INVOICE_HISTORY
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BROKER_INVOICE_HISTORY 
   PRIMARY KEY(brok_dlr_code, ba_trxn_date_from, ba_trxn_date_to);
```

there is no record with same brok_dlr_code but executing the script with same ba_trxn_date and ba_trxn_date_to dates but raises error as

```
ORA-20005: ORA-00001: unique constraint violated
```

Comment: why primary key not only use brok_dlr_code?

Comment: did you issue this sql `select count(1) from invoice group by brok_dlr_code,ba_trxn_date_from,ba_trxn_date_to having count(1)>1` and see returns without data?

Comment: "*there is no record with same brok_dlr_code*" - yes there is, otherwise you wouldn't get that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were few records already got inserted, then again running the script cause the script to begin inserting same data. This caused unique constraint violation. Hence old data had to be truncate and re-run the script will not cause this unique constraint.